# How to append values taken from SQL to multiple hashes and then compare them

Tags: algorithm, perl, mariadb, hashtable

I want to store the values taken from my database into hash. Then, I want to compare and see if they have the same `material`. If they have the same `material`, I want to compare the `txt`. If the `txt` is different, I want to use storedisp. If the text is the same, I want to use coursemat:

```
my $stmt1 = qq(select txt, price, material from coursemat);
my $sth1 = $pagev->runQ($stmt1); #run query in house function
my $stmt2 = qq(select material from storedisp);
my $sth2 = $pagev->runQ($stmt2);

while(my ($txt, $price, $material) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  %cmhash = (
    $material => {
      txt => $txt,
      price => $price,
    },
  );
}

while(my $txt = $sth->fetchrow) {
  %sdhash = (
    $material => {
      txt => $txt,
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? What's the problem? (Hint: see [mcve] and [edit] your question to include one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following replaces all existing values in the hash:

```
%cmhash = (
  $material => {
    txt => $txt,
    price => $price,
  },
);
```

Replace the above code with the following:

```
$cmhash{$material} = {
    txt => $txt,
    price => $price,
};
```

This assumes the values of `$material` are unique.